# Lodash - Filter nested collection by array of prop value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Say the original collection is:

```
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3
  }]
}, {
  id: 4,
  children: [{
    id: 5
  }]
}]
```

Want to filter it with this given values of `id` property:

```
var selectedIds = [1, 3, 4]
```

The results should be:

```
var result = [{
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 3
  }]
}, {
  id: 4,
  children: []
}]
```

How to accomplish this using Lodash methods?

Comment: What if the `selectedIds = [1, 3, 5]` ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 What's the difference?

Comment: Please mention what should happen if the child id **(5)** in `selectedIds` but parent isn't **(4)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `filter` together to apply filter on nested element,

```
_.map(data, elem => {
    elem.children = _.filter(elem.children, child => selectedIds.includes(child.id));
    return elem;
});
```

NOTE: Assuming the filter has to be applied only on `children` property.

To not modify the original `data`,

```
_.map(data, elem => {
    let children = _.filter(elem.children, child => selectedIds.includes(child.id));
    return Object.assign({}, elem, {children});
});
```

Comment: You're using the original element (`elem`) and reassigning the `children` property, which means you'll lose the original list of children. It would be better to create a new return object that clones the propertys of the original element and leaves the old one intact (and unmodified).

Comment: Yes, @THEtheChad. This will modify the original `data`. Added solution to not modify that too.

Comment: Should then `_.filter` those `children.length > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to recursively walk your collection (and each item's children). I don't believe lodash has a native way of implementing this. I wrote a function called `matcher` that takes the collection and selected ids, and returns items that match those ids, and passes the children in and does the same thing. I wasn't sure how to handle a situation where a parent isn't selected but the children are.... I just assumed you'd throw them all away.

Point is, you have a very particular structure (items and children that are items) that requires you to write a specific recursive function that knows how to walk that structure.

```
const matcher = (collection, selected) => _.reduce(collection, (result, item) => {

  if (selected.includes(item.id)) {
    result.push({
        id: item.id,
        children: matcher(item.children, selected)
    })
  }

  return result
}, [])

const result = matcher(data, selectedIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for id and take only children with wanted id.

```js
function getParts(array, ids) {
    return array.reduce((r, { id, children }) =>
        r.concat(ids.includes(id)
            ? { id, children: getParts(children || [], ids) }
            : []
        ), []);
}

var data = [{ id: 1, children: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] }, { id: 4, children: [{ id: 5 }] }];

console.log(getParts(data, [1, 3, 4]));
console.log(getParts(data, [1, 3, 5]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```